# How do you overwrite instead of append to a text file in Android?

Tags: android, file, input

```
File myDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myDir + "/score.txt");
fw.write("Hello World");
fw.close();
```

The above code appends to the text file. How do you make it overwrite?

Answer (score 5):

Javadocs are your friend:

[FileWriter JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

Supply `false` for the second (boolean) argument and you will overwrite rather than append.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myDir + "/score.txt", false);
```

Comment: Well, it should be overwriting then :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(myDir + "/score.txt", false);
```